# How can I prove that this encryption scheme from a random oracle is secure?

Tags: encryption, hash, random-oracle-model

I am reading this example:

> A *random oracle* is an ideal object.
>
> What makes a random oracle convenient for proofs is the part about knowing nothing on the output for a given input if you do not try it. For instance, consider the following encryption scheme:
>
> - $H$ is a random oracle which outputs $n$-bit values.
> - The key is a $K$, a string of $k$ bits.
> - A single message $m$ is encrypted by computing $c = m \oplus H(K || 1) || H(K || 2) || ...$ (you repeatedly "hash" with the random oracle the successive strings obtained by concatenating $K$ with a counter, and you concatenate the oracle outputs into a big stream which is XORed with the message to encrypt).
>
> If $H$ is a random oracle, then it is reasonably easy to prove that the encryption is secure up to a work factor of $2^{k-1}$ invocations of $H$.

How I will be able to prove that that the encryption is secure up to a work factor of $2^{k-1}$?

pdta: I think that the encryption is secure up to a work factor of $2^{k}$.

Comment: Look up what "secure up to $x$" means. (The details might differ for each author.) I suppose it means something like "with $x$ invocations, the attacker has a chance of 50% to break the scheme".

Comment: in this case $50\% = 2^{k-1}$ invocations?

Comment: The plain old bruteforce key search will need $2^k/2 = 2^{k-1}$ invocations on average, or for a 50% chance. Your job would be to show that there can't be a faster algorithm.

Comment: attacks are made ​​with the same hash function $H$ or could be another?. I make this question because I am read other example Lemma2 (pp13)[1], and here use two random oracles: $Hash_z$ and $Gen$

[1]http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.5.9666

Comment: In that paper $Hash$ is a function with fixed length output (and variable length input), while $Gen$ has a fixed length input and arbitrary length output. (Se section 4.1 for the notations.) Normally we name the latter one *Random number generator*, not *hash function*, though we want similar security properties for both.